# Why can I use a reference to non-const with 'auto' but not with 'std::pair' in range-based for-loop through 'std::unordered_map'?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stl, auto

Using C++14 (should also affect C++11) I'm confused about `auto` in a range-based for-loop through an `std::unordered_map`, in contrast of using the exact type like `std::pair<int, int>` in the code below.

More specifically I have some (related) questions concerning the example:

- Question 0: (loop 0) Why is `std::pair<int, int> &` not allowed but `auto &` in loop 1 is?
- Question 1: (loop 1) Why/How/When does `auto` differ from the exact type (like `std::pair<int, int>` in loop 0)?
- Question 2: (loop 2) Why are this different pointers than in loop 3?
- Question 3: (loop 3) Why are this the same pointers for all map entries?
- Question 4 (continues 0 and 1): I know that the range-based for-loop uses an iterator. But why can I iterate through an `std::unordered_map` with reference to non-const using `auto` (loop 1), but not when using `std::pair` (loop 0)?

---

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;
    map[3] = 333;
    map[2] = 222;
    map[1] = 111;

    // loop 0
    // QUESTION 0: Why is `std::pair<int, int> &` not allowed but `auto &` in loop 1 is?
    // for(std::pair<int, int> & pair : map)
    //     pair.second++;

    // loop 1
    for(auto & pair : map)
        // QUESTION 1: Why/How/When does `auto` differ from the exact type (like `std::pair<int, int>` in loop 0)?
        pair.second++;

    // loop 2
    for(auto const & pair : map)
        // QUESTION 2: Why are this different pointers than in loop 3?
        std::cout << pair.first << " (" << &pair.first << ") : " << pair.second << " (" << &pair.second << ")" << std::endl;

    // loop 3
    for(std::pair<int, int> const & pair : map)
        // QUESTION 3: Why are this the same pointers for all map entries?
        std::cout << pair.first << " (" << &pair.first << ") : " << pair.second << " (" << &pair.second << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can run the code here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/rkBkKDatf

Comment: A `std::unordered_map<int,int>` does not hold instances of `std::pair<int,int>`.  It holds `std::pair<const int, int>`.  So all your `pair<int,int>` are temporary copies.  I think that answers all 5 of your questions.

Comment: See `value_type` here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map note in your case it will be `std::pair<const int, int>`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast and helpful answers! Was my first question here and I'm glad to have you all. :-)

Comment: What is the type of `std::map<K, V>::value_type` ? It is not `std::pair<K, V>`.

Comment: @MartinYork No, it's `std::pair<const K, V>` (note the `const`), as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and verify [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/HyDPx9H5f).

Comment: @saluto: Thanks. I knew the answer before asking.

Comment: @MartinYork Ok, and now I know it too. ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value type of a `std::unordered_map` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. See [the documentation at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Hence, you cannot use `std::pair<int, int>&` as the type to iterate over the contents of such an object.

---

That explains why

```
for(std::pair<int, int> & pair : map) { ... }
```

does not work.

---

The following works

```
for(auto const & pair : map)
```

since the type is deduced for you by the compiler.

---

The following works

```
for(std::pair<int, int> const & pair : map)
```

since `pair` is bound to a temporary object of type `std::pair<int, int>` constructed from a `std::pair<const int, int>`.